# Does there exist a provably correct and recipient hiding encryption scheme?

Tags: public-key, zero-knowledge-proofs, commitments

I am looking for an encryption scheme $E$ and a commitment scheme $C$ which allow

1. encrypting the message $m$ for the public key $y$ as $e = E_y(m)$, so that the ciphertext $e$ does not reveal any information about the recipient public key $y$
2. committing to $y$ and $m$ as $c_y = C(y)$ and $c_m = C(m)$,
3. to prove that the ciphertext was correctly formed with respect to committments to $y$ and $m$.

That is, given a ciphertext $e$ and commitments to the message and key, $c_m, c_y$, it should be possible to construct a zk-proof that the ciphertext was correctly formed with respect to the commitment openings:

$PK\{ (y,m): c_m = C(m) \land c_y = C(y) \land e = E_y(m)\}$.

Using elgamal encryption there are known methods for proving correct encryption (e.g. section 3.3 of [Stadlers PVSS](https://www.ubilab.org/publications/print_versions/pdf/sta96.pdf)). However these methods rely on revealing the public key of the recipient, which is not acceptable in my case. Is there away around this problem?